# Add Comment help text

Tags: feature-request

I noticed on another stack exchange site, when you clicked "add comment", you got a little run down on the mini-markup in the comment section:

[image: Mini Markup Help]

This doesn't exist in the Network Engineering SE.  Is there a way we could get that added?  If that is simply another available customization we can add to our stack exchange, then maybe we should have a discussion about what the ideal verbiage to have in there might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formatting help slide-out is implemented network-wide, but it is only shown to users with reputation under 100. You saw it on Information Security because you have 94 reputation there.

Comment: I see.  Thats too bad.  Because, I seem to always be forgetting the syntax for a creating a link in comments text.

Comment: @Eddie, the Help Center has an explanation on [Comment Formatting](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).